# Joining every row of table 1 to table 2

Tags: sql

I have two tables identical to each other like below

table 1

```
col1
1
2
3
4
5
```

table 2

```
col1
1
2
3
4
5
```

is there way to write a SQL query to join every row of table 1 to every row of table 2?

Comment: `cross join` perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: Show us what is your desire result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want a Cartesian product?  If so, use `cross join`:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an inner join as they are identical tables:

```
select t1.col, t2.col, ...
from table t1
inner join t2 on t1.col = t2.col
```